# Partially editing a document in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, real-time, real-time-data

This is a conceptual question regarding the realtime editing of large files. Imagine we have a 50 Mb txt file in Google Drive that we want to allow users to edit. We require that the user downloads the entire file before they start editing (The user will have to wait for a while, but this is ok). The user then changes a single word in the 50 Mb text file. How can we possibly update the file in Google Drive without uploading all 50 Mb of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating an Android application, the [Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) handles this differential upload for you behind the scenes.

If you are not using the Android API, it is not currently possible via the Drive RESTful API.

Answer (score 0):

You say the files are "txt" which suggests they are not Google docs. Drive considers all such files to be blobs. so I can't see anyway they can be patched.